# Convert string of list into list of int

Tags: python, list

how do I convert a string of integer list into a list of integers?

Example input: (type: string)

```
"[156, 100, 713]"
```

Example conversion: (type: list of int)

```
[156, 100, 713]
```

Comment: remove first and last char of the string then split ', '
I think it's not efficient, so I ask it here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
import ast
res = ast.literal_eval('[156, 100, 713]')
```

[Read more about ast.literal_eval in python docs.](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#module-ast)

Answer (score 2):

use `ast.literal_eval` on it and you're done.  Here you don't have all the security issues of regular `eval` and you don't need to worry about making sure your string is well formed, etc.  Of course, if you really want to parse this thing yourself, you can do it with a pretty simple list-comprehension:

```
s = "[156, 100, 713]"
print [ int(x) for x in s.translate(None,'[]').split(',') ]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> import json
>>> a = "[156, 100, 713]"
>>> json.loads(a)
[156, 100, 713]
```